# What makes diffculty to make a human bio-tooth compare to a mouse's?

Tags: human-biology, stem-cells, biomedical-engineering

Some time ago I read a news article that said a bio-engineered tooth based on a mouse's would be available around 2015. There was some research about it at King's College in the UK, and many other institutes.

Now, I haven't heard any news that such a thing is available. It seems to be a basic result of stem-cell research, how much difference can there be between a human's tooth and a mouse's?

Comment: So what is your question - When will a bionegineered tooth be available? or What is the difference between mouse's tooth and human's? These two questions should be asked seperately in different posts

Comment: @TanMath - these two questions are likely very much related, as preclinical animal work typically precedes human stuff. This seems fine.

Comment: @AliceD but I find that asking about the difference of two animal's teeth and when bio-teeth are available as two questions that should possibly put in two seperate posts..Plus, this question seems opinion-based as well...

Comment: Thanks AliceD, anyway I will write more clearly next time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to this 2013 announcement from King's College, [Biological tooth replacement -- a step closer](http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2013-03/kcl-btr030813.php). So called "BioTeeth" are sought after because

> Current implant-based methods of whole tooth replacement fail to reproduce a natural root structure and as a consequence of the friction from eating and other jaw movement, loss of jaw bone can occur around the implant.

However, Professor Sharpe identified the following obstacle:

> What is required is the identification of adult sources of human epithelial and mesenchymal cells that can be obtained in sufficient numbers to make biotooth formation a viable alternative to dental implants.

For some background, consult [Biological tooth replacement (2006; Sartaj, Sharpe)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2100358/)

Unfortunately the 2013 article was the last I heard of it - possibly for the aforementioned reason. If you're really interested, you might consider attempting to contact Professor Sharpe yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your link and information about obstacle, jzx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is necessary for making "Bio-teeth". It should be more expensive and without any advantage comparing the ceramic teeth or others...

The different between mouse and humans teeth is that mouse' teeth, like toenail, will keep growing, thus they need to shave their teeth all the time. That is the reason they are always eating, and like to bit some stuffs even are not food. But humans teeth stop growing and cannot grow back once broken. There is no point to make a Bio-tooth for mouse. But for human, for the economy point too, there is no reason to make a Bio-tooth..... I can't image any advantage for making Bio-teeth

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation about the difference. I wanted to know why the research was difficult even though it was successful on mouse long time ago. Because the bio-tooth has a root structure, I believe that it can be on the ligament instead of directly connecting to jawbone like an implant. At least, wouldn't it reduce the pain when an implant is being installed in gum?